# Скорость преобразования lexical_cast

Tags: boost, c++

Посмотрел [ссылочку](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/performance.html). Для меня это весьма серьезный аргумент для использования `lexical_cast` вместо `stringstream`. Хочу узнать - почему `lexical_cast` оказывается таким шустрым? И каковы побочные эффекты от его использования (возможно, раздувание кода)?

P.S. в C++11 наконец-то ввели [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string). Интересно сравнение с ним то же.

Comment: Код раздувается прилично. Впрочем, это проблема многих бустовских библиотек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для простых преобразований это действительно очень удобная вещь. Но там, где нужно серьезное форматирование, он оказывается непригоден. Тут stringstream незаменим. Также никакой поддержки локализации и т.п. В такой ограниченной функциональности и причина его скорости. А сишным функциям типа sprintf еще приходится строку форматирования разбирать и т.п.

Есть еще одна отличная библиотека в бусте - boost.format. Позволяет форматировать вывод в стиле POSIX sprintf + еще разные добавления. Но типобезопасна и все такое. Очень удобна Два минуса: медленная и код раздувает очень основательно.

Кстати, lexical_cast  при невозможности преобразования выбрасывает исключения, а std::to_string нет.